# How to define a query timeout for a spring data elastic search query?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

My question is more in general assuming i have a simple query like this to elastic search

```
Page<MyEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

I want to be able to set a timeout for this query for instance so it doesn't hang forever, although I read the documentation I didn't see anything clear about how to do it.

Is the any way to do it? a way to set a timeout for Spring-data-elasticsearch queries that I can make sure that nothing will get for too long?

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving a 'timeout' in a search request query is using the **'timeout' parameter in the query itself.** [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-body.html)

Lets assume we want to perform a full-text 'match query', we can add 'timeout' before the query itself:

```
 {
    "timeout": "1ms",
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "description" : "This is a fullText test"
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to use Elasticsearch time units as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/common-options.html#time-units) and ship them as String values.

**In your case** - I don't see any way to achieve this using spring-data-es repository, but - you can add custom functionality to your repository and use the ElasticsearchIndexTemplate with the matchAllQuery() (java elastic api),

Something like that (**haven't tested it**):

```
    nodeEsTemplate.getClient().prepareSearch("test-index")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
            .setTimeout(TimeValue.timeValueMillis(1))
            .execute().actionGet();
```

As nodeEsTemplate is of type ElasticsearchIndexTemplate and assuming you have created a custom findAllWithTimeOut method in your repository class.